# SharedPreference not creating file in Device File Explorer location

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

1. I am creating a login activity using firebase mobile authentication. After successful authentication I get success
   callback from firebase.
2. After getting successful callback response, I am saving login ID(mobile number) and loginStatus in SharedPreference.
3. Before some time it was creating the file in Device File Explorer(data/data//prefs) folder

I didn't even change the login of saving, but still it stopped working,
Instead it's creating xml file in this location

*/data/user/0//shared_prefs/AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME.xml*

But also, while reading this file, it gives false as loginStatus which was saved as true earlier.
Here is my Code. Thanks in advance.

..........Saving........

```
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_USER_LOGGED_IN, true);
                        editor.putString(Constants.MOBILE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
                        editor.apply();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                         if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            //TODO
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

................Reading Back the SharedPreference.........

```
                SharedPreferences prfs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean loginStatus = prfs.getBoolean(Constants.IS_USER_LOGGED_IN, false);
                if(loginStatus){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }else{
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
```

mContext holds the Activity Context;
Please help.

Comment: Try editor.commit(); instead as you finish();

Comment: working with  'editor.commit()', why it's not working with apply() now? and why was it working before using editor.apply().  I am confused with this.

Comment: Apply() is asynchronous. Maybe the activity is already destroyed before it gets applied. It was just a thought. Commit() is executed directly on the main thread and hence before you call finish().

Comment: so Asynchronous execution of 'apply()' needs activity context?